# spark DataFrame using explode and describe functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark DataFrame having 3 columns(id: Int, x_axis: Array[Int], y_axis: Array[Int]) with some sample data below:

[image]

want to get basic statistics of y_axis column for each row in dataframe. Output would be something like:

[image]

I have tried explode and then describe, but could not figure out expected output.
Any help or reference is much apprecieated

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest, you could explode the Y column and then use a window over id to compute all the statistics you are interested in. Nevertheless, you want to re aggregate your data afterwards so you would generate a huge intermediate result for nothing.

Spark does not have a lot of predefined functions for arrays. Therefore the easiest way to achieve what you want is probably a UDF:

```
val extractFeatures = udf( (x : Seq[Int]) => {
    val mean = x.sum.toDouble/x.size
    val variance = x.map(i=> i*i).sum.toDouble/x.size - mean*mean
    val std = scala.math.sqrt(variance)
    Map("count" -> x.size.toDouble, 
        "mean" -> mean, 
        "std" -> std, 
        "min" -> x.min.toDouble, 
        "max" -> x.max.toDouble)
})

val df = sc
    .parallelize(Seq((1,Seq(1,2,3,4,5)), (2,Seq(1,2,1,4))))
    .toDF("id", "y")
    .withColumn("described_y", extractFeatures('y))
    .show(false)

+---+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |y              |described_y                                                                                  |
+---+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|Map(count -> 5.0, mean -> 3.0, min -> 1.0, std -> 1.4142135623730951, max -> 5.0, var -> 2.0)|
|2  |[1, 2, 1, 4]   |Map(count -> 4.0, mean -> 2.0, min -> 1.0, std -> 1.224744871391589, max -> 4.0, var -> 1.5) |
+---+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And btw, the stddev you calculated is actually the variance. You need to take the square root to get the standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this approach using UDF. spark DataFrames offers a function called "describe" to be used for getting basic stats and returns a new DF. wondering if we could use that instead of our UDF logic.
My bad for incorrect values of stddev.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Spark's describe function is meant to compute statistics on full columns of a given dataframe and there is no simple way to compute it on windows.
A trick to use describe anyway would be to either split your dataframe in K dataframes, K being the number of distinct IDs. Yet this is completely against Spark's spirit and would be extremely expensive so I clearly recommend using the UDF approach.